# How to configure multiple HttpClient instances with different configurations in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to configure multiple API urls in the Program.cs class in Blazor WASM. I'm not seeing an AddHttpClient extension like in server-side. Was wondering if anyone had an alternate solution for this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
var firstURI = new Uri("https://localhost:44340/");
var secondURI = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");

void RegisterTypedClient<TClient, TImplementation>(Uri apiBaseUrl)
   where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
   builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
   {
       client.BaseAddress = apiBaseUrl;
   });
}

// HTTP services
RegisterTypedClient<IFirstService, FirstService>(firstURI);
RegisterTypedClient<ISecondService, SecondService>(secondURI);
```

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2019/09/mutliple-httpclients.aspx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can be done with Blazor Client Side. First, in your client-side package, get the following nuget package: **Microsoft.Extensions.Http**

Then, create two classes for this example (normally you would use an interface, but a class  on its own should work here. I am going to demonstrate two different base addresses being used so you know there is a difference.

```
   public class GoogleService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public GoogleService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public string GetBaseUrl()
        {
            return httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And the Yahoo Service:

```
  public class YahooService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public YahooService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public string GetBaseUrl()
        {
            return httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Next, in your Client Program's Program.cs, you can do something like the following:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<GoogleService>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com/");
            });

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<YahooService>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yahoo.com/");
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Next, you can inject them into your front end like so, and see that they are indeed two different injected clients:

```
@page "/"
@inject BlazorHttpClientTest.Client.Clients.GoogleService googleService;
@inject BlazorHttpClientTest.Client.Clients.YahooService yahooService;

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<label>Google Address:</label><label>@googleAddress</label>
<label>Yahoo Address:</label><label>@yahooAddress</label>

@code{
    string googleAddress;
    string yahooAddress;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        googleAddress = googleService.GetBaseUrl();
        yahooAddress = yahooService.GetBaseUrl();

    }
}
```

And just like that, you should have it working:

[image]

Let me know if you need me to explain anything else more in depth, otherwise, mark as answered if it works for you.

Comment: I knew I was missing an extension, and there it is. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The current answer seems overly complicated.

You can simply use named HttpClients and inject the `IHttpClientFactory` into a page instead and create a HttpClient for a specific named configuration.

e.g. This example provides both an authorised client and an anonymous one (to access anonymous server endpoints).

### in program.cs:

```
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorApp.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Anonymous", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

### in the razor page

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;
```

and use with

```
var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("Anonymous");
var someData = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SomeData>($"api/someendpoint");
```

Comment: While this works, using named services adds it's own debt that we must pay later, using a typed service encapsulates all the configuration and magic strings to a single code file. I don't want to see `"Anonymous"` and `"BlazorServer.API"` magic strings in my implementation files ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller you can solve the magic string like all others, with a constant HttpClientNames constant class. This is much better than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be heaps late. But I wanted to add that if you have many clients you want to register, you can always create a client factory extension and then add in the clients reading from appsettings.json into your programs.cs

```
public static class ClientFactoryExtension{
public static void AddClientAbstractFactory<THandler>(
    this IServiceCollection services, 
    string clientName, 
    string url)

    where THandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    // register handler
    services.AddTransient<THandler>();

    // register client
    services.AddHttpClient(clientName, client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<THandler>();

}
```

}

Then you can create a method that lets you register all your clients like so:

```
public static class ClientServices{
public static IServiceCollection AddClientServices(this IServiceCollection Services, IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    Services.AddClientAbstractFactory<Client1AuthorizationMessageHandler>(
            "client1", Configuration.GetValue<string>("client1:BaseUrl"));
    Services.AddClientAbstractFactory<Client2AuthorizationMessageHandler>(
            "client2", Configuration.GetValue<string>("client2:BaseUrl"));
    Services.AddClientAbstractFactory<Client3AuthorizationMessageHandler>(
            "client3", Configuration.GetValue<string>("client3:BaseUrl"));

    return Services;
}
```

}

And finally in programs.cs, you can do the following:

```
builder.Services.AddClientServices(builder.Configuration);
```

And done.